# Overall Checklist Percentage completed

Tags: trello

Is there a way to see the total percentage completed of all card checklists?
All I want to do is to get a total percentage for all checklists on all cards across all lists, so I can see how far I am from finishing the whole current project.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently.
Card lists don't have overview features of their cards, though I agree list overviews would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can find is a Chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/list-progress-bar-for-tre/klhahganeobopkelbdeljamclomlhhjg?hl=en

Comment: If you are affiliated with the project, please disclose that in your answer.  Adding more detail as to *why* this solution works for the question would also be very helpful. Thanks!